# Get a number from JSON by Promtail

Tags: json, grafana-loki, promtail

I use Promtail+Loki to collect my logs.
Input logs are JSON strings that look like this:

```
{ "severity":"error",  "msg":"very bad error", "duration":20 }
```

How can I parse this string by Promtail to get duration as numeric in Loki?
My goal is to be able to make queries like this:

```
{job="job_name"}|duration>10s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following PromQL should work:

```
{job="job_name"} | json | duration>10
```

You can't use values like "10s", but you can use "10K" or "10M" ones.